# How can I add custom body CSS for different pages in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making a multi-page website and trying to add different CSS to the body for different pages.

I'm using `react-router-dom` to handle routing, and I have my files set up like this:

**Main.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// Other imports for pages here

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<MyPage />}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<AnotherPage />}></Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import Main from './Main';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}
```

export default App;

**index.js**

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly set inline styles on the `<body>` element inside the component for each route.

For example:

```
function MyPage() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '14px';
    // return some JSX...
}
```

To reset the style when the component is unmounted, `useEffect` can be applied.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
function MyPage() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const origFontStyle = document.body.style.fontSize;
        document.body.style.fontSize = '14px';
        return () => document.body.style.fontSize = origFontStyle;
    }, []);
    // return some JSX...
}
```

You could consider extracting this into a custom hook for more convenient usage.

Comment: Literally posted something similar just before seeing this haha. Though I never knew about `useEffect()` . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution, though not sure if it's good practice, but it works.

I set the body class at the beginning of each page component, before returning it.

For example:

```js
const MyPage = () => {
  // Set the css class
  document.body.setAttribute('class', 'my-class'):

  return (
    // Component code
  );
}
```

Only thing is, I have to set this on every single page component, to ensure the body CSS of one component doesn't carry into another.